# REST: How to manage "not in" queries

Tags: rest

Suppose I have a RESTful api with Team and Players, many to many relationship.

I can get the players from a specific team with:

```
GET /api/team/{team_id}/players
```

I would like to make some more complex querys, but I don't know which is the best practice for uri design.

Specifically I want to:

1. Get players that are NOT part of any team.
2. Get players that are NOT part of a specific team.

What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If teams and players have a many to many relationship I personally wouldn't use this uri design. If a player can play for more than one team then you will end up with player uris that are not unique. For example say that a particular player plays for both team 5 and team 6, they might be represented by both the following uris (assuming teams and players both have numeric ids)

```
/api/team/5/players/4
/api/team/6/players/4
```

Instead I would move things around a bit, you could represent the player with this uri:

```
/api/players/4
```

And each team with these uris (pluralized for consistency)

```
/api/teams/5
/api/teams/6
```

Then you can search for members of teams like this

```
/api/players?team=5
```

NOT IN queries are open to interpretation, but you could so something similar to how django model filters work and introduce suffixed query parameters along these lines:

```
/api/players?team_ne=5
```

For players not in any team you have a few options

```
/api/players?team=
/api/players?team=none
```

Perhaps the second of those is less ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

Route syntax like

```
/api/team/{team_id}/players
```

require defined team_id allways.

Use GET params to filter with this property.